# Auto sort newly updated data

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, spreadsheet

I need help on creating a function on how to auto sort from the most updated data. I am trying to create my own manga update tracker, I usually only update the chapter number which is on column 3 or create a new data, what I want is to auto move the entire ROW to the first ROW which is ROW 3.

Thanks for the help guys.

[image: Sample data]

Comment: Please explain "manga"

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).
See [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

You may find it easiest to always enter new data on row 2. See the [autoInsertRowAtTopOfSheet_](https://support.google.com/docs/thread/73783836?msgid=73796266) script for an example of how to automatically insert a row at the top when you start editing row 2.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function onMyEdit(e) { 
  //e.source.toast("Entry");
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  if(sh.getName() == "Sheet1") {
    //e.source.toast("Flag1")
    const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
    const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
    sh.getRange(3, 1, sh.getLastRow() - 2, sh.getLastColumn()).sort({column:3,ascending:false});
  }
}
```

I changed it to an installable trigger so you will have to create it manually or write a script to create in using methods in ScriptApp.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I'll try to check it if I have time. Once again, very much appreciated.

Comment: I just tried your code and when I debug it, theres on error here: sh.getRange(3,1,vs.length,vs[0].length).setValues(vs).  I don't know how did i trigger it. Can you help me fix it?

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: I don't exactly know why is there an error, it just highlighted on that line. By the way, I added the function on the onEdit trigger

Comment: I just tested it and it continues to work for me.

Comment: Did you use it on the onEdit trigger?

Comment: I did not see anything about an onEdit trigger in the question. How do you wish the onEdit trigger to work?

Comment: May I ask how did you test it? 

What I meant that everytime I edit or update the data, it will automatically move it on the first row, I mean on the row 3

Comment: I keep on experimenting on how to make it work but theres really no luck for me. I even tried it onEdit(e)

Comment: I'll ask again how do you wish the onEdit function to work.  It's clear to me what  you are asking currently this code is just sorting the data base upon column c

Comment: Basically that's what I want and since I'm not quite sure on how to execute the script, thats why I'm trying to make it execute the autosort command everytime a data will be updated

Comment: By the way, heres the link of the spreadsheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1HqS4DcrfGtQSWPnd9XGvG5E1mPSDiAoXkuvGp2-CYcQ/edit?usp=drivesdk

Comment: It's not a public link.  Do you know that you are revealing you email address?